# Get custom attribute value

Tags: c#

I need to get the value of a custom attribute. My requirement is almost similar to the example given in this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx) (reproduced below).

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

// An enumeration of animals. Start at 1 (0 = uninitialized). 
public enum Animal {
    // Pets.
    Dog = 1,
    Cat,
    Bird,
}

// A custom attribute to allow a target to have a pet. 
public class AnimalTypeAttribute : Attribute {
    // The constructor is called when the attribute is set. 
    public AnimalTypeAttribute(Animal pet) {
        thePet = pet;
    }

    // Keep a variable internally ... 
    protected Animal thePet;

    // .. and show a copy to the outside world. 
    public Animal Pet {
        get { return thePet; }
        set { thePet = value; }
    }
}

// A test class where each method has its own pet. 
class AnimalTypeTestClass {
    [AnimalType(Animal.Dog)]
    public void DogMethod() {}

    [AnimalType(Animal.Cat)]
    public void CatMethod() {}

    [AnimalType(Animal.Bird)]
    public void BirdMethod() {}
}

class DemoClass {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        AnimalTypeTestClass testClass = new AnimalTypeTestClass();
        Type type = testClass.GetType();
        // Iterate through all the methods of the class. 
        foreach(MethodInfo mInfo in type.GetMethods()) {
            // Iterate through all the Attributes for each method. 
            foreach (Attribute attr in
                Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(mInfo)) {
                // Check for the AnimalType attribute. 
                if (attr.GetType() == typeof(AnimalTypeAttribute))
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Method {0} has a pet {1} attribute.",
                        mInfo.Name, ((AnimalTypeAttribute)attr).Pet);
            }

        }
    }
}
/*
 * Output:
 * Method DogMethod has a pet Dog attribute.
 * Method CatMethod has a pet Cat attribute.
 * Method BirdMethod has a pet Bird attribute.
 */
```

In the above code, the custom attribute is cast to its type (`AnimalTypeAttribute`) and then its value obtained. I have a similar scenario, but I do not have the reference of the custom attribute, and therefore cannot cast it to obtain its value. I am able to obtain the attribute node, however, I'm unable to find its final value.  In the above example, the attribute is 'AnimalTypeAttribute' and its values are 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', etc. I'm able to find the attribute node 'AnimalTypeAttribute', what I now need are the values 'Dog', 'Cat', etc.
Is there a way this can be done?

Additional info (not sure if it changes anything): I'm creating a custom FxCop rule, and the node type I have is `Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.AttributeNode`.

TIA.

Comment: But if you haven't the reference to the custom attribute, what do you want to achive? What is the use casE?

Comment: Can you show code you are working on instead of MSDN example?

Comment: @alekkowalczyk Working on a custom FxCop rules project, which is independent of the actual project. The attribute is contained in the actual project.

Comment: @MikkaRin My code is almost the same, cannot post it here. If this example works, so will mine. :)

Comment: @Fahad Since you have the attribute in your current project, the type of this attribute will be a <nameOfAttribute>+"Attribute". So if you have attribute [Something(somefiled)] - the type for this attribute will be SomethingAttribute. Hope it will help you

Comment: @MikkaRin I'm able to find the attribute, the trouble is finding it's value. In the above example, the attribute is 'AnimalTypeAttribute' and its values are 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', etc. I'm able to find the attribute node 'AnimalTypeAttribute', what I now need are the values 'Dog', 'Cat', etc. Sorry if I was not clear before. I'll edit the question and add this there as well.

Comment: @Fahad, try a dynamic cast: `((dynamic)attr).Pet)`

Comment: @Fahad - What .net version are you compiling against? When I copy-paste your example, and compile against 4.5, it works like it should.

Comment: @ASh the dynamic cast doesn't work either.

Comment: @theB The example is taken directly from MSDN and it works. I've explained what I needed in the question. I've got the solution now tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.AttributeNode` cannot be cast to a normal `System.Attribute`, `System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData`, or anything else that I tried. Finally, I could get the value I was looking for using the following function:

```
public Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Expression GetPositionalArgument(int position)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use the strong type, you have to use reflection.

A simple example :

```
Attribute[] attributes = new Attribute[]
{
    new AnimalTypeAttribute(Animal.Dog),
    new AnimalTypeAttribute(Animal.Cat),
    new AnimalTypeAttribute(Animal.Bird)
};

foreach (var attribute in attributes)
{
    var type = attribute.GetType();
    var petProperty = type.GetProperty("Pet");
    var petValue = petProperty.GetValue(attribute);
    Console.WriteLine("Pet: {0}", petValue);
}

// Output:
// Pet: Dog
// Pet: Cat
// Pet: Bird
```

Comment: This also does not work for my situation. Turns out the node I have (Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.AttributeNode) does change things. The 'type.GetProperty(string)' always returns null. Thanks anyway.